# TSQL change in query to and query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have one  to many relationship table

```
ReviewId     EffectId
1       |    2
1       |    5
1       |    8
2       |    2
2       |    5
2       |    9
2       |    3
3       |    3
3       |    2
3       |    9
```

In the site the users select each effect he chooses, and I get all the relevant review.
I make an `in` query
For example if the user select effects 2 and 5
My query: “

```
select reviewed from table_name where effected in(2,5)
```

Now I need get all the review that contain both effect
All reviews  that has effect 2 and effect 5
What is the best query to make this?
Important for me that the query will run as quick as possible.
And for this I can  also change the table schema (if needed ) like add a cached  field that contain all the effect with comma  like

```
Reviewed      cachedEffects
1          |  ,2,5,8
2          |  ,2,5,9,3,
3          |  ,3,2,9
```

[image]

Comment: what output you want

Comment: Your current design is OK .Don't change to comma separated come rain or shine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
 select reviewid
 from 
 tbl
 where effectid in (2,5)
 group by reviewid
 having count(distinct effectid) > 1
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RIXVO58954)

`count (distinct effectid)` is used to ensure that the results contain only those `reviewID`s which have multiple records with different values of `effectID`. The `where` clause is used to filter out based on your filter condition of having both 2 and 5.

The key thing to note here is that we are grouping by `reviewID`, and also using the count of distinct `effectID` values to ensure that only those records which have both 2 and 5 are returned. If we did not do so, the query would return all rows which have `effectID` equal to either 2 or 5.

For improving performance, you could create an index on `reviewID`.